# create a query that fetch data as XML more faster with filters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

i'm using SQL server 2014, trying to get xml from SQL server in an hierarchical structure,
`

```
WITH
parent as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where NodeLevel =  0),
FirstNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from parent)),
SecondNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from FirstNode)),
ThirdNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from SecondNode)),
FouthNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from ThirdNode)),
FifthNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from FouthNode)),
SixthNode as (select ModelId,ParentIdFK,ModelName,Expanded,SortOrder from model where ParentIdFK in(select ModelId from FifthNode)),
XmlData as (select (select p.*,L1.*,L2.*,L3.*,L4.*,L5.*,L6.* from parent p
left join FirstNode L1 on  L1.ParentIdFK =p.ModelId 
left join SecondNode L2 on L2.ParentIdFK=L1.ModelId
left join ThirdNode L3 on L3.ParentIdFK=L2.ModelId
left join FouthNode L4 on L4.ParentIdFK=L3.ModelId
left join FifthNode L5 on L5.ParentIdFK=L4.ModelId
left join SixthNode L6 on L6.ParentIdFK=L5.ModelId
for xml auto , ROOT('ModelLines'),type) as XMLDataModel) 
(select @data = XMLDataModel from XmlData)
```

`

and i got outPut as

```
  <model ModelId="11" ParentIdFK="3" ModelName="Sedans" Expanded="0" SortOrder="1">
      <model ModelId="14" ParentIdFK="11" ModelName="328i Sedan" Expanded="0" SortOrder="1">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="15" ParentIdFK="11" ModelName="328xi Sedan" Expanded="0" SortOrder="2">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="16" ParentIdFK="11" ModelName="335i Sedan" Expanded="0" SortOrder="3">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="167" ParentIdFK="11" ModelName="Sheilas Model" Expanded="0" SortOrder="3">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="289" ParentIdFK="11" ModelName="335xi Sedan" Expanded="0" SortOrder="3">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
    </model>
    <model ModelId="12" ParentIdFK="3" ModelName="Sports Wagon" Expanded="0" SortOrder="2">
      <model ModelId="17" ParentIdFK="12" ModelName="328xi Sports Wagon" Expanded="0" SortOrder="1">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="18" ParentIdFK="12" ModelName="328i Sports Wagon" Expanded="0" SortOrder="2">
        <model>
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
      <model ModelId="214" ParentIdFK="12" ModelName="Convertible" Expanded="0" SortOrder="4">
        <model ModelId="223" ParentIdFK="214" ModelName="328i Convertible" Expanded="0" SortOrder="1">
          <model />
        </model>
        <model ModelId="224" ParentIdFK="214" ModelName="335i Convertible" Expanded="0" SortOrder="3">
          <model />
        </model>
      </model>
    </model>
```

this query too 2s, but there is a lot of nodes without attributes

so i tried `set @data.modify('delete //model[empty(@ModelId)]')` to remove these nodes
this takes nearly 30s. can anyone suggest a faster and better way to fetch xmal faster

Comment: `to remove these nodes this takes nearly 30s` so are you asking if there's a faster way at removing nodes and or fetch xml without the nodes you don't need? It's not really clear what you are wanting to accomplish in my opinion. For what you are doing, `modify` is correct, this [method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) takes an XML DML statement to insert, update, or delete nodes from XML data, what would make you think you could speed this up? Again, IMHO, the query would need to be changed to exclude the nodes you don't need.

Comment: (continued) Then you wouldn't need the `modify` method at all, only get what you need.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Somebody, somewhere knows the SQL XML query well enough to answer, but most people look at queries like that and run away (too complex, brittle, and tough to support).  My approach, is to just write a simple SQL query, get just the data you need, and shape it with XSL / XML Linq or similar.    Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication164
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement[] models = doc.Descendants("model").ToArray();

            for (int i = models.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (models[i].Attributes().Count() == 0)
                {
                    models[i].Remove();
                }
            }

 
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: How does this address the issue in sql? How is this solution faster and relevant?

Comment: The code posted is in c# so what does SQL have to do with issue?  The xml string is being processed in c#.

Comment: The OP is using XML in `sql`, hence (`for xml auto`), not `c#`...

Comment: You are saying the op query above isnt sql query?